# Problem navigate to previous screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to switch between screen in flutter, when i switch screen from main screen to second screen it work fine whenever i press back button from Second Screen the app become black and it show error message 5243 pos 12 history is not empty: is not true

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'second_screen.dart';


 void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return const MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: HomeScreen(),

);
}
}

 class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 const HomeScreen({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: null,

  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 12.0, top: 28.0, right: 12.0, bottom: 12.0),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [

          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [

                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){

                   Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
const SecondScreen()));

                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        margin: const 
     EdgeInsets.only(right:12.0),
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                      child: const Text('click me  to jump'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.grey
                ),

              ],

            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  }
```

and here is my second screen code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


 class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget{
 const SecondScreen({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 home: _SecondScreen() ,

  );
  }

}

   class _SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return  WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return false;
  } ,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
    ),

    body:  Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Go back to First Screen'),
        onPressed: () {
          // Navigate back to the first screen
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ),

  ),
); }
```

what i have done mistake any assist appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: 5243 pos 12 history is not empty: is not true

Comment: do you have initiate in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `MaterialApp` in second screen and use scaffold instead
(you don't need to use Material app in every screen, its a one time thing)

Update Your Code like this

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


 class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget{
 const SecondScreen({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return false;
  } ,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
    ),

    body:  Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Go back to First Screen'),
        onPressed: () {
          // Navigate back to the first screen
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ),

  ),
);
  }

}
```

Comment: okay thanks for optimising code suggestion. but my problem is still there ...?

Comment: removing MaterialApp in your second screen will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

you are using  Navigator.pushReplacement

pushReplacement is used when you don't need to back. it will remove all your previous routes.

try to use Navigator.push

-> Navigator.push used to keep you all previous routes.

example:

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
const SecondScreen()));
```